# how to apply a function to rows of a table in a loop

Tags: python, function, loops, pandas

I have a simple function which reads in two latitudes and if they are near each other it will return 'idle'

```
def is_idle(lat1, lat2):

    if lat1 - lat2 < 0.1:
        return 'idle'
    elif lat1 - lat2 > 0.1:
        return 'active'
    else:
        return 'error'
```

how would i apply this in a loop to pairs of rows in a loop on python?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like? You tagged `pandas` but didn't mention using a dataframe. Are lat1 and lat2 columns in a dataframe? Can you provide and example of what the output should be after running the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
def is_idle(lat1, lat2):

    if lat1 - lat2 < 0.1:
        return 'idle'
    elif lat1 - lat2 > 0.1:
        return 'active'
    else:
        return 'error'


lats = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in range(len(lats)-1):
    lat1= lats[i]
    lat2 = lats[i+1]
    is_idle(lat1,lat2)
```

Comment: this is perfect but as i am only dealing with latitude (just to test function) they are all in one column. so i need a for loop where it will do row_n+1 - row_n, then row_n+2 - row_n+1 and so on

Comment: sorry yes. is this better?

Comment: well played. it works perfectly. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use map and lambda and zip instead of the for loop:

```
lats = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L = zip(lats[:-1], lats[1:]) # L = [(1,2),(2,3), ...]
map(lambda l: is_idle(l[0],l[1]), L)
```

or

```
map(lambda l: is_idle(*l), L)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize the original question is regarding for loops, however I would suggest that this is a good example of when not to use a `for loop`.

Here's my solution:

```
def is_idle2(e):
    if e > 0.1:
        return 'idle'
    elif e < 0.1:
        return 'active'
    return 'error'

lats = pd.Series([5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]*100000)

(lats - lats.shift(1)).dropna().map(is_idle2)
```

Timings:

```
#my solution
%timeit (lats - lats.shift(1)).dropna().map(is_idle2)
10 loops, best of 3: 185 ms per loop

#Currently accepted solution
%%timeit
for i in range(len(lats)-1):
    lat1= lats[i]
    lat2 = lats[i+1]
    is_idle(lat1,lat2)
1 loops, best of 3: 15.8 s per loop
```

Doing this without a for loop is about 100 times faster on a decently sized series.